# SQL query from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, I need some help,

I want to find out confirmed (confirmed=1) reservation date with last name `Steven`

Can some one help for with the this SQL Query

**table_member**

```
+-----------+-----------+
|Member_id  | last_name |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | David     |
| 2         | owen      |
| 3         | Tom       |
| 4         | Steven    |
| 5         | Steven    |
| 6         | Steven    |
| 7         | Steven    |
| 8         | Steven    |
| 9         | Steven    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

**table_resevation**

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|resvationID|Member_id  | day       |   month   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         |   1       |     6     |
| 2         | 1         |   2       |     6     |
| 3         | 2         |   1       |     6     |
| 4         | 4         |   1       |     6     |
| 5         | 4         |   2       |     6     |
| 6         | 5         |   1       |     6     |
| 7         | 5         |   2       |     6     |
| 8         | 7         |   3       |     6     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Confirm**

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|confirmID  |resvationID| confirmed |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         |   1       |
| 2         | 2         |   1       |
| 3         | 3         |   0       |
| 4         | 4         |   0       |
| 5         | 5         |   1       |
| 6         | 6         |   1       |
| 7         | 7         |   0       |
| 8         | 8         |   1       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are the confirmations stored in a separate table? I mean, if I'm assuming correctly that there's one confirmation per reservation, then the `confirmed` column could easily reside in `table_reservation`, thus eliminating the need for an extra table (=extra join).

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this work for you?

```
 SELECT
     m.Member_ID, m.Last_Name,
     r.Day, r.Month, 
     c.ConfirmID
 FROM 
     table_member m
 INNER JOIN 
     table_reservation r ON r.Member_ID = m.Member_ID
 INNER JOIN
     Confirm c ON c.resvationID = r.resvationID
 WHERE
     m.Last_Name = 'Steven' AND c.confirmed = 1
```

Comment: @marc_s-why can't we use equijoin?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar: `INNER JOIN` ***IS*** equi-join ... [see Wikipedia on that topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.*, r.*, m.*
from confirm c
left join table_reservation r on c.reservationID = r.reservationID
left join table_member m on m.member_id = r.Member_id
Where c.confirmed = 1
and m.name = "Steven"
```

I did not test it, but that should point you to the way.

(Edit: second "where" was a typo)

Comment: Why use `LEFT JOIN` ?? I don't see any need for that. Also: you cannot have two `WHERE` statements - there cannot be a second `WHERE` after the `AND` ...

Comment: Yes he can use inner join too. Depends on what he likes to get. Anyway he will at least find an Idea what to do. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Apply inner join on all table

```
select day,month from table_reservation inner join table_member on table_member.member_id=table_reservation.member_id
inner join confirm on confirm.reservationid=table_reservation.reservationid where confirm.confirmid=1
and table_member.last_name like 'Steven'
```